# Power Automate: Create/Update record in List B from List A

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, powerapp

I want to:

1. Trigger flow when listA has a new record or is modified.
2. Determine whether this record exists in listB.
3. If it exists, update this record, if it does not exist, create a new record

My flow:

[image]

[image]

Current result - nothing is being written to List B.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you check your flow run to determine what is the output of length condition check action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make below changes to flow:

1. First of all, remove "Apply to each" action from "If yes" block and use create item action directly using data from trigger outputs (from "When an item is created or modified").
2. For **Update item** action, use "ID" from outputs of get items action (Or simply using the expression like `item()?['ID']`) and data from trigger outputs (from "When an item is created or modified").

[image]

It should work for you.

Comment: Also, add space between `eq` and `'` in Filter Query of get items action (if not added already) just to make sure the action returns correct item from list B like: `Title eq '<Request_ID>'`

Comment: Thanks! its working! although its not creating every EXISTING record from List A, just newly created or updated entries its CREATING in List B. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to create a manual flow for that (one time activity). Create a manual flow which will get all items from list A, use apply to each for looping for all results, then do the same steps to check if item exist in list B, create / update item in list B accordingly.

Comment: Please create another question if you are unable to follow above steps and provide link to it here in comments. I will try to explain the answer in detail on new question / post.

Comment: I seem like I am able to create a one time manual flow.. but.. only brnging over max of 100 items! why is that?

Comment: How many items are there in the list? You can mention up to 5000 in "Top Count" property of get items action. If you have more than 5000 items, you have to enable pagination from settings of "Get items" action. Here you can fetch maximum 100000 items.

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to make sure you have a unique identifier in both lists which can be used to check if the item exists in another list or not. make that column Unique on both lists.
- Your flow is correct, one issue I see is that while creating the item, you are looping through the response of getting Items action. **It should directly create an item using the data of When the Item is created or modified action**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Okay it seems to be creating the one Item I change in List A now. 
Not sure where going wrong. It is missing the Creating of all Items from List A to List B, and Also the Update part of a record is not working. 

I just have create item on the left side now, and all my references are using dynamic expression and come from "When Item is Created or Modified"  I wonder where Im going wrong here... Could it be "ID" ?  I dont actually have an ID field in List B, but I have one in List A. Not sure why it does in the List B update Item area.