# Power Automate, Update Item ID Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow

How do I update item? My work is not working because I think ID are not matching between lists.

What is ID here?  I am trying to update records.

[image]

ID in list B:

[image]

ID in list A:

[image]

So how do I match these up?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up from your another post at: [Power Automate: Create/Update record in List B from List A](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305076/power-automate-create-update-record-in-list-b-from-list-a),

For **Update item** action, use "ID" from outputs of get items action (Or simply using the expression like `item()?['ID']`) and data from trigger outputs (from "When an item is created or modified").

Do not use "ID" from trigger outputs as those will not be same in both the lists.

[image]